# Inserting formulas to a row based off the value of a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to insert specific formulas and values across a row depending on the value from a drop down box rather than manually inserting these formulas and defeating the purpose of the drop down.

Edit: I used the Data validation to create the drop down, but I'm using this for an accounting purpose. So the drop down will have the type of transaction and I'm wanting the defined formulas used for that specific transaction to insert across the row. Below is part of my data sheet, and I want the formulas corresponding to the transaction type to be inserted into my other sheet where the drop down is, and have the formulas correspond with the drop down response.

[image: part the data sheet]

Comment: We understand your goal.  To help you we need more details.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right, you can use "Data Validation" for this task:

[image: Data Validation]

In the example above, the range `A2:A7` defined as `List`, and I refer to it in the Data Validation dialog. In the range `List` you can place any formula you like.

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Sorry, this was an on the side project and I got bogged down with classes, but that's not exactly what I'm going for. I have one sheet that has a list of varying transactions and beside them there are varying formulas in the accounts that I'm wanting to affect. I've been able to apply the list feature, but I'm wanting the corresponding XX number of cells to be added as well to a determined space to the right of the drop down list.